# Auto-complete text in the datagridview for single column only

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I tried to provide auto-complete text in datagridview. But, I got auto-complete text in all column and after clicking on third column (with combobox) application start displaying error on editing other cells.

**I want auto-complete text box in *first column i.e. "Name" only***. I cannot manage code so that **auto-complete doesn't show in second column i.e. "Age"** and also **error not occurred after clicking on combobox column.**

The code is As follow.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub appData(ByVal data As AutoCompleteStringCollection, ByVal c As String)
        data.Add("Ravi")
        data.Add("Raj")
        data.Add("Raja")
        data.Add("r " & c)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Try
            MsgBox(e.Control.ToString)
            Dim header As String = DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText
            If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox AndAlso header.Equals("Name") AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
                If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
                    Dim text As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
                    If text IsNot Nothing Then
                        text.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                        text.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

                        Dim data As AutoCompleteStringCollection = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
                        appData(data, DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString)
                        text.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data
                    End If
                Else
                    Dim text As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
                    text.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Nothing
                    text.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
                    text.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColName", "Name")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColAge", "Age")
        Dim ComCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        ComCol.Items.Add(1)
        ComCol.Items.Add(2)
        ComCol.HeaderText = "Combobox Col"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ComCol)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a test in Else clause as :

```
If header.Equals("Name") Then

                If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
                    Dim text As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
                    If text IsNot Nothing Then
                        text.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                        text.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

                        Dim data As AutoCompleteStringCollection = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
                        appData(data, DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString)
                        text.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
                    Dim text As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
                    text.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Nothing
                    text.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
                    text.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
                End If
            End If

   Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: This way does not solve the error occurred after clicking third (combobox) column.

Comment: You can solve this issue by handling the even "DataGridView1_DataError" like :  have a look at my answer i have edit it for you .Hop that solve your probleme  >mark answer please

Answer (score 0):

Use just :

```
If header.Equals("Name") Then
```

instead of :

```
   If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox AndAlso header.Equals("Name") AndAlso 
     DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, using only single condition you have mentioned the problem is partly solved, auto-complete display in single column, but still after clicking on last column cell, on click of other cell there is an error occurred.

Comment: Ok have a look at my second answer,don't forget to vote up and mark answer please

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing is firing more often than you realize.

Perhaps you should just do your autocomplete work on form load event instead?  That way, it only has to run once...

The 'autocomplete work' I'm talking about, being this part:

```
                text.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                text.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

                Dim data As AutoCompleteStringCollection = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
                appData(data, DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString)
                text.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data
```