# Search database using datagridview column C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to  search database using a datagridview column(something like a load event)
For now  I am able  to search database using a textbox  and a load event like this:

```
         SqlCommand cmdauto= new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct pNAME FROM tbl_product", connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader readershifra = cmdauto.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollectionshifra = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                mycollectionshifra.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
            txtpname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollectionshifra;
            connection.Close();
```

My question is , how can I do a execution like above but instead in textbox , to be able to type in datagridview column[1]
For example I start typing on column[1] and I get a autocomplete suggestion

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Autocomplete in a textbox is a different thing. Use your database query to populate [the textbox's autocomplete source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You should appreciate that when a datagridview is showing a textbox you can type into, that it is the only textbox in the whole grid. The datagridview just moves the same textbox around, into position for whichever cell wants to be edited. As such you can set up its autocomplete source and then when it's editing a cell in whatever column you can turn the autocomplete on.  Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053423/auto-complete-text-in-the-datagridview-for-single-column-only